# Entity Framework - How to copy exact DateTime value to a column that has default value GETDATE()?

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework, default-value

In the POCO, I have this:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
```

At migration, I have this set:

```
CreatedDate = c.DateTime(defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()")
```

This is so I don't have to set `myNewEntity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now` when I create it, and I get the current database date saved once it gets inserted in the database, as expected.

I'm migrating the data from this table to another table who also has the same `CreatedDate` declaration/setup as above. The problem is, setting `myNewEntityInNewTable.CreatedDate = myOldEntity.CreatedDate` won't work. The `CreatedDate` on insertion will be the current database system date as declared, not the old entity's `CreatedDate`. I want this behavior for live insertions, but not for migrating data to the new table. What do I need to do?

Note: I am not able to use SQL Management Studio's import tool because I also have to perform code-level data conversion. Even if I could, I think that the default GETDATE() will still win and save the current system date.

Comment: Why does the migration have to be done with entity framework?

Comment: Tell me how else I can migrate. I have to perform other operations in C# as part of the migration (like convert XML to JSON for one of the columns), for example. I have to work with the EF DbContext, or else, I would have to use plain SQL in C#, which I'm avoiding like a plague.

Comment: why is it a computed column if you're inserting the value yourself?

Comment: It's a computed column because I want it that that way ultimately. I just didn't want it for migration. I guess I'll have to omit those settings when I first create the new table, migrate, then run another migration to make it computed, which I was trying to avoid if possible.